# Highlight text on single click - epiphany address bar

Tags: settings, epiphany

Is there a way to do what the subject line says? I know in Firefox the default is to not highlight all text in address bar on single click. But this is easily changed in about:config. Is there a way for force this in Epiphany(Web)???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on the favicon next to the address (not the favicon on the tab).